# SPSS: How would I create a column summing up means / medians / range from Compare Means function?

Tags: spss

I'm trying to sum up across a row for different numerical variables that have been processed through the `Compare Means` function.

Below (without the last 'Total' column') is what I have generated from Compare Means; I'm looking to generate the last Total column.

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|        | Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 | Total |  
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
| Mean   |    10 |     1 |     2 |       |  
| Median |     4 |    20 |     4 |       |  
| Range  |     6 |    40 |     1 |       |  
| Std.dev|     3 |     3 |     3 |       |  
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Here's the syntax of my command:

```
MEANS TABLES=VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3
  /CELLS=MEAN STDDEV MEDIAN RANGE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really imagine what the use is for summing these values, but forget about why - this is how:
The OMS command takes results from the output and puts them in a new dataset which you can then further analyse, as you requested.

```
DATASET DECLARE  MyResults.
OMS  /SELECT TABLES  /IF COMMANDS=['Means'] SUBTYPES=['Report']   /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV   OUTFILE='MyResults' .
* now your original code.
MEANS TABLES=VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3   /CELLS=MEAN STDDEV MEDIAN RANGE.
* now your results are captured - we'll go see them.
omsend.
dataset activate MyResults.
* the results are now in a new dataset, which you can analyse.
compute total=sum(VAR_1, VAR_2, VAR_3).
exe.
```